# How were Chinese Communist POWs treated after the civil war?

Tags: china, civil-war, prisoners-of-war

I was watching the film ‘The Assembly’ and the opening scene involved a battle where Chinese Nationalist troops had surrounded a group of Chinese Communists and were about to overrun them. Before the assault, the Chinese Nationalist commander offered the surrounded Communist troops a chance to surrender. They refused and successfully fought off the assault.

This scene made me wonder about what happened to Chinese Communist troops after the civil war who chose to surrender to the Nationalists during the conflict. Did the majority flee China with the Nationalists? Did the Nationalists use Chinese Communist POWs as part of prisoner exchange deals with the mainland Communist regime? Did Chinese Communist POWs simply shift back into main land Chinese society quietly, with the Communist government choosing to look the other way, so long as they kept a low profile? Or did the Chinese Communist regime treat POWs of the Nationalists very harshly, regardless of the circumstances of their capture, and subject them to some kind of “re-education” process? Finally, were Chinese Communist POWs of the Japanese treated differently altogether?

Comment: They generally were punished just for being captured. Those who actually surrender would be lucky to not get shot.

Comment: "After the civil war?" Did the civil war end? Isn't there still an island province that is in a state of rebellion, and has not yet been reunited with the rest of China?

Comment: Semaphore - by analogy with how other Communist regimes behaved e.g. the Soviet Union to those of its soldiers who had become prisoners of the Germans in world War II, and how ruthless Mao could be, I can well believe what you say. However, do you have any sources or evidence to confirm it?